# Pass Data from View Controller MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, segue

I realise there are solutions for passing data from view controllers. However, the problem I am having is I am using Map Kit and I am unsure which Pin will be clicked on it could be one of the following:

```
 artworkPin = Artwork(title:"Wind Wand",locationName:"Majestic",discipline:"Statue",
                             coordinate:windwandcoord)
 artworkPin2 = Artwork(title:"Wind Wand2",locationName:" Not Majestic",discipline:"Statue",
                         coordinate:windwandcoord2)
```

I want the label on the ViewTwo (second view controller) to appear as the title of the pin's "info" button that was clicked on. I currently have it setup as:
        var artworkPin: Artwork!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    art_title.text = artworkPin.title
```

which only loads the label as the title of artworkPin ( the first pin ). 
attached code if necessary:
[ViewTwo](http://pastebin.com/MxVjjAua/)
[ViewControllerOne](http://pastebin.com/eVMqaaKj)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the problem I am having is I am using Map Kit and I am unsure
>   which Pin will be clicked on

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        if let artworkPin = view.annotation as? Artwork {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "no", sender: artworkPin)
        }
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "no" {
            if let artworkPin = sender as? Artwork {
                let ViewTwo = segue.destination as! ViewTwo
                ViewTwo.artworkPin = artworkPin
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this goes in at the end of ViewController One? EDIT: was missing } testing now...

Comment: Tested it now and the info buttons now do nothing. e.g: when clicked on no response occurs. [Updated View One] (http://pastebin.com/pVJDh7b7) [Artwork.swift] (http://pastebin.com/ysQ2Gqme)

Comment: Nope, the info button still doesn't open the second UI View, I think it might be due to how you changed the segue? Because now there is no `performSegue(withIdentifier: "no", sender:self)` line?

Comment: I thought a new approach, no need `mapView(_:didSelect:)` function. Let try once more time!

Comment: Success! Thanks for that! While I have you here is there some other way I can contact you? I am trying to do essentially this same thing except I want to be able to transfer an image and description for each pin.

Comment: You can contact me through skype: danhh.gl

Comment: Thanks, have sent you a request :)